# Duplicity cron not working

Tags: linux, encryption, cron, cryptography, duplicity

I'm trying to run Duplicity backups via a cron script with `--encrypt-key` and a GNUPG key ID (from `gpg --list-secret-keys`).

It's failing with `/root/backup.sh: 5: --encrypt-key: not found` but if I manually run the line as root then it works fine.

Any ideas?

backup.sh:

```
test -x $(which duplicity) || exit 0
. /root/.passphrase

export PASSPHRASE
$(which duplicity) --encrypt-key SOMEKEYID /mnt/nas01 b2://SOMEBACKBLAZETHING@nas01
```

.passphrase is just a text file containing the GPG key password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your script is faulty.

looks like `which` cannot find `duplicity` returns empty and your shell tries to run program `--encrypt-key` which obviously won't work.

so first remove `$(which ...)`, so it'll complain about not finding `duplicity` thereafter.

some cron implementations do not set a default `PATH` env var. that's probably why duplicity is not found. solve that by adding it on top of your crontab or provide a full absolute path to the binary.

..ede/duply.net

Comment: Thank you! I copy/pasted that script from somebody who I assumed knew way more than I did about bash scripts :-) I usually just manually enter the full path to the binary. I'll give this a shot then and see what happens.